# python appending does not work while using multiprocessing

Tags: python, list, multiprocessing, append

So the problem is that appending "e" to my list "ok = []" does not have an effect, but that is weird considering that, when doing print(e) just one line above ok.append(e), the value of "e" is printed out as it should.

no need to understand the program and what it does, the main issure here is just that appending some value to my list does not have effect, even though the value is real.

I tried to use ok = [] inside of `if __name__=='__main__':` however that gave me the error `NameError: name 'ok' is not defined` so i then tried to use "global ok" inside of "some_function" however that gave me the same results

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

ratios1 = [1/x for x in range(1,11)]
ratios2 = [y/1 for y in range(1,11)]

x = 283
y = 436

ok = []

def some_function(x_, y_):

    list_ = [[a, b] for a in range(1, 1980 + 1) for b in range(1, 1980 + 1) if a / b == x_ / y_]
    for e in list_:
        if not e[0] in [h[0] for h in ok]:
            if not e[1] in [u[1] for u in ok]:
                print(e)
                ok.append(e)


if __name__=='__main__':

    processes = []

    if x / y in ratios1 or x / y in ratios2:
        some_function(x_=x, y_=y)
    else:

        for X_, Y_ in [

            [x, y],
            [x - 1, y], [x, y - 1], [x + 1, y], [x, y + 1],
            [x - 2, y], [x, y - 2], [x + 2, y], [x, y + 2],
            [x - 3, y], [x, y - 3], [x + 3, y], [x, y + 3]

        ]:

            p = mp.Process(target=some_function, args=(X_,Y_))
            processes.append(p)

    start = time.time()

    for p_ in processes:
        p_.start()

    for p_ in processes:
        p_.join()

    end = time.time()

    print(f"finished in {end - start} sec")
    print(ok)
```

when running this is output:

```
[...]                                   # other values of "e"
[283, 433]                              # some random "e" value
[566, 866]                              # some random "e" value
[849, 1299]                             # some random "e" value
[1132, 1732]                            # some random "e" value
finished in 0.8476874828338623 sec      # execution time
[]                                      # the "ok" list being printed out at the end
```

after adding print(id(ok)) both in "some_function" and in the end, it gives me the following output:

OBS: I removed print(e) for this output

```
2489040444480
3014871358528
2324227431488
2471301880896
1803966487616
2531583073344
1665411652672
2149818113088
2330038901824
1283883998272
2498472320064
2147028311104
2509405887552
finished in 0.8341867923736572 sec
2589544128640
[]
```

Comment: could you add the line `print(id(ok))` both in `some_function` and at the end?

Comment: @thomas i get diffrent values each time on "ok" when doing that, i edited my main post to show you those values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a list that can be accessed from more than one process, which is made by using a [`multiprocessing.Manager.list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Manager), and you have to pass it as an argument, you cannot have it as a global, as inheriting globals is OS sepecific.

using a managed list is slower than a normal list, so if you find the performance unacceptable you should really try to work with only local variables and forget about using globals, as IPC is an expensive process.

```py
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

ratios1 = [1/x for x in range(1,11)]
ratios2 = [y/1 for y in range(1,11)]

x = 283
y = 436

def some_function(x_, y_, ok_list):

    list_ = [[a, b] for a in range(1, 1980 + 1) for b in range(1, 1980 + 1) if a / b == x_ / y_]
    for e in list_:
        if not e[0] in [h[0] for h in ok_list]:
            if not e[1] in [u[1] for u in ok_list]:
                print(e)
                ok_list.append(e)


if __name__=='__main__':
    manager = mp.Manager()
    ok_list = manager.list()
    processes = []

    if x / y in ratios1 or x / y in ratios2:
        some_function(x_=x, y_=y)
    else:

        for X_, Y_ in [

            [x, y],
            [x - 1, y], [x, y - 1], [x + 1, y], [x, y + 1],
            [x - 2, y], [x, y - 2], [x + 2, y], [x, y + 2],
            [x - 3, y], [x, y - 3], [x + 3, y], [x, y + 3]

        ]:

            p = mp.Process(target=some_function, args=(X_,Y_,ok_list))
            processes.append(p)

    start = time.time()

    for p_ in processes:
        p_.start()

    for p_ in processes:
        p_.join()

    end = time.time()

    print(f"finished in {end - start} sec")
    print(ok_list)
```

Comment: thanks alot, another thing im wondering about. Is it possible for be to run this entire program (with different x and y) by using multiprocessing. i think that would be nested-multiprocessing. nut sure if it works

Comment: @Neverland1337 it will work just fine, just convert all the code in your main into a function and run it using multiprocessing, nesting is possible.

Comment: @Neverland1337 a pool would be better for this that way you will actually make use of multiprocessing if you only turn main into a function you run with multiprocessing it will not significantly speed up the script.

Comment: @Neverland1337 added this too my Answer and it runs in 2.1 seconds this way

Comment: @thomas to be honest this logic should run in less than a few milliseconds if it was properly optimized ... but this is not really what this question is about.

Comment: i tried putting the entire program into " def main(x,y) "  and then i runned it using main(283,436) - however i get the following error:  AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'main.<locals>.some_function'

Comment: @Neverland1337 you should put only the things inside your `if __name__ == "__main__":` to be inside this new `main` functions, don't define functions inside other functions.

Comment: @AhmedAEK im sorry i dont understand, what is it i should move you mean?

Comment: @Neverland1337 don't have one `def` inside another `def`, if you want to define a function define it outside of the other function, in other words you should have 2 separate functions inside your file ,`some_function` and `main`.

Comment: @AhmedAEK the point is that there is no real benefit to simply running main with multiprocessing, when you want to run the same function with different parameters a pool is the better way to go. At least from my understanding.

Comment: @AhmedAEK thanks, yes it works now. may i ask why you cant define a fuction inside a function? I have seen alot of programs do this, and i think its called nested functions. I have used nested functions alot before without errors.

Comment: @Neverland1337 something that has to do with how python works and how multiprocessing work under different operating systems, and how pickle works, and it just takes a days of reading before you really realize why you cannot use this mix together, so just keep all functions defined outside of one another (which is the proper way to define functions) and everything should work, don't use hacky code just because it "worked for me once before".

Answer (score 0):

This should work, the problem was that when you start the process the objects it uses are not really passed to it as much as they are cloned. Using `muliprocessing.Pool.starmap` allows us to return values from the process which circumvents this issue.
We use `starmap` and not just `map`, so that we can pass multiple parameters to `some_function`. Additionally the `Pool` lets you replace the `for X_,Y_ in ...` loop and run it multiprocessed.

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Pool

ratios1 = [1/x for x in range(1,11)]
ratios2 = [y/1 for y in range(1,11)]

x = 283
y = 436

ok = []

def some_function(x_, y_):

    list_ = [[a, b] for a in range(1, 1980 + 1) for b in range(1, 1980 + 1) if a / b == x_ / y_]
    for e in list_:
        if not e[0] in [h[0] for h in ok]:
            if not e[1] in [u[1] for u in ok]:
                print(e)
                ok.append(e)
    return ok

if __name__=='__main__':

    processes = []
    res=[]

    if x / y in ratios1 or x / y in ratios2:
        some_function(x_=x, y_=y)
    else:
            start = time.time()
            with Pool(13) as p:
                res = p.starmap(some_function, [[x, y],
                    [x - 1, y], [x, y - 1], [x + 1, y], [x, y + 1],
                    [x - 2, y], [x, y - 2], [x + 2, y], [x, y + 2],
                    [x - 3, y], [x, y - 3], [x + 3, y], [x, y + 3]])
            ok = res
            end = time.time()

    print(f"finished in {end - start} sec")
    print(ok)
```

Comment: something does not work about this, its says its finished in 0.51 sec but it takes about 5. maybe its not waiting because there is no .join() ?.. and also the "ok" at the end does not give me the full list that I should normally get. And i think the program should take about 1sec not 5sec.

Comment: @Neverland1337 I made an edit to the code, I believe it now gives the entire list. The time is correct, but it is only counting the execution of the last call of `some_function` not every call. That is why the time is similar to before. If you want to change the time to be for the entire call then you need to change the position of the start = time.time()` before the `for _X, _Y in ..` line.

Comment: i get the full list now, but the time it takes for me to receive the " print(ok) " output is about 5sec

Comment: @Neverland1337 with everything the way it is now it will give the time for the entire run time and run in less than 2.2 with everything being done multiprocessed

Comment: if you are doing more tasks than the number of cores in your processors you'll find the results are wrong because you are using `ok` as a global variable ... which is wrong, don't use global variables in multiprocessing as you have no control over which process this code will run in, in some cases it might all just run in a single process, and you'll get  duplicate entires of OK in output, so this code doesn't actually work, either make every worker create its own version of `ok` inside the function or pass a `manager.list` to the workers to use, but don't use a global variable.

Comment: @AhmedAEK due to the same reason the original code did not work as intended this will work, the global variable is not modified by the processes.

Comment: each process has its own version of it, and if this code ran inside a single process, this process's global list will be modified and you will get this problem, just don't use global variables.